# How to subclass `tf.train.Saver()`?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow-slim

I’m training on `colaboratory` which sometimes loses the connection to the server. After 90 mins of inactivity the VM will also reset.

I want to override `tf.train.Saver.save()` with a callback so that I can copy the checkpoint to my Google Cloud Storage account on a time or step interval.

see: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py

```
#
# override tf_saver, add callback after save()
#
import os
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.training import saver as tf_saver

## override saver
class Saver_with_callback(tf_saver.Saver):
    _callback_op = None
    def __init__(self, callback_op, **kwargs ):
        self._callback_op = callback_op
        super(tf_saver.Saver, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def save(self, sess, save_path, **kwargs):
        """
        see: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py

        """
        model_checkpoint_path = super.save(sess, save_path, **kwargs)
        if self._callback_op is not None:
            ## call on a new thread?
            self._callback_op(sess, save_path, 
                              model_checkpoint_path=model_checkpoint_path, 
                              **kwargs)
        return model_checkpoint_path
```

But i get an error when I run `slim.learning.train(saver=callback_saver)`

```
    final_loss = slim.learning.train(train_op, log_dir, 
                        init_fn=init_fn,
                        global_step=global_step,
                        number_of_steps=steps,
                        save_summaries_secs=300,
                        save_interval_secs=600,
                        saver=callback_saver,
                        #    saver=tf_saver.Saver(),                                     
                       )
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-41-dfb09327cccd> in <module>()
    149                         save_summaries_secs=300,
    150                         save_interval_secs=600,
--> 151                         saver=callback_saver,
    152 #                         saver=tf_saver.Saver,
    153                        )

/anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/slim/python/slim/learning.py in train(train_op, logdir, train_step_fn, train_step_kwargs, log_every_n_steps, graph, master, is_chief, global_step, number_of_steps, init_op, init_feed_dict, local_init_op, init_fn, ready_op, summary_op, save_summaries_secs, summary_writer, startup_delay_steps, saver, save_interval_secs, sync_optimizer, session_config, session_wrapper, trace_every_n_steps)
    730       save_summaries_secs=save_summaries_secs,
    731       save_model_secs=save_interval_secs,
--> 732       init_fn=init_fn)
    733 
    734   if summary_writer is not None:

/anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/supervisor.py in __init__(self, graph, ready_op, ready_for_local_init_op, is_chief, init_op, init_feed_dict, local_init_op, logdir, summary_op, saver, global_step, save_summaries_secs, save_model_secs, recovery_wait_secs, stop_grace_secs, checkpoint_basename, session_manager, summary_writer, init_fn)
    304     self._meta_graph_def = meta_graph.create_meta_graph_def(
    305         graph_def=graph.as_graph_def(add_shapes=True),
--> 306         saver_def=self._saver.saver_def if self._saver else None)
    307     self._is_chief = is_chief
    308     self._coord = coordinator.Coordinator()

AttributeError: 'Saver_with_callback' object has no attribute 'saver_def'
```

``

`isinstance(callback_saver, tf_saver.Saver)==True` and if I use `saver=tf_saver.Saver()` it works fine.

Comment: I tried to use the `apscheduler` python `cron` lib, but I got a TimeZone error––I don't think its configured. 

`UnknownTimeZoneError: 'Can not find any timezone configuration'`

Comment: Did you consider saving the checkpoints to dropbox or other synced directory? This could be organized faster than writing this question

Comment: I'm using google `colaboratory`, not sure if dropbox is supported by the vm

Comment: As the variable ```saver_def``` is set in the ```__init__``` method of the base ```Saver``` class on every call to ```__init__```, I suspect Saver's ```__init__``` method is not being invoked. I would use the new python3 ```super().__init_(...``` just for safety, and then look into Tensorflow's ```@tf_export("train.Saver")``` decorator which may be messing with stuff.

Comment: still learning python, does this invoke `__init__` correctly: `super(tf_saver.Saver, self).__init__(**kwargs) `?  I'm not familiar with the decorator construct

Comment: @Maxim I managed to get `gcsfuse` to mount a bucket to the local fs with `colaboratory`. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OM0mXcn7mYp_bl-C_FiAo54xLs7R3y8A/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @michael Why are you importing `from tensorflow.python.training` instead of usual `tf.train`, any specific reason? Also, you don't need to give arguments to super, do it as `super().__init__(**kwargs).

Comment: @A.Queue sorry, I didn't see your last comment (I was traveling) but it was the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not calling the `__init__` function of `tf_saver.Saver` in `Saver_with_callback.__init__()`.

The `__init__` function of the parent class of `tf_saver.Saver` was called when you call `super(tf_saver.Saver, self).__init__(**kwargs)`.

This is because `super(tf_saver.Saver, self)` returns the parent class of `tf_saver.Saver`, not `tf_saver.Saver` itself as you're expecting.

You should call

`super(Saver_with_callback, self).__init__(**kwargs)`

or for Python3, simply

`super().__init__(**kwargs)`

Comment: I made the following changes and it worked fine `super().__init__(**kwargs)` and `model_checkpoint_path = super().save(sess, save_path, **kwargs)`